# SQLite on Android: insertWithOnConflict() returning ever-increasing results for same data sets

Tags: android, sqlite

**PROBLEM BACKGROUND:**
I have two tables where the Primary Key's are Text fields.

When I repeatedly use `SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(myTable, null, myValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)` with the same data, I see ever increasing values being returned.

So it looks like INSERT is being performed (instead of REPLACE) for the same data sets.

**PROBLEM:**
However, looking at these tables with "SQLite Database Browser" I see the correct number of records that I'd expect when REPLACE is performed.

The root to my confusion is the description Android documentation that states :
*Returns
the row ID of the newly inserted row OR the primary key of the existing row if the input param 'conflictAlgorithm' = CONFLICT_IGNORE OR -1 if any error*

**QUESTION:**
Why is it that a REPLACE is done, but the row ID of the existing data isn't returned ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me like it is doing exactly what you are asking it to? You are asking it to *replace* and it does exactly that. It will remove the old row and insert the new one.

It would leave the old row and return that ID if you instead passed `CONFLICT_IGNORE`.

Comment: If I have three rows: A, B, C and I pass in another A I was expecting it to replace the existing A and return a 1. But I suppose what it does is remove the existing A and the new row is number 4

Comment: This is exactly what it is supposed to do based on the documentation. It removes row A (Row 1), and re-inserts it as row A (which is now Row 4 since it is a NEW Insert after Row 3). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence... no, CONFLICT_IGNORE should not be used.  It does not work as expected.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13045

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
insertWithOnConflict(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues,
SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ABORT);
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"name found before plz, change it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```